# Typescript type predicate to narrow on generic type for 'this' with strange compiler error

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-types

How can I write a type predicate class method to return true if the instance has a given specific generic type?

This does not work:

```ts
type DD = 'a' | 'b';
class Flagged<T extends DD> {
    constructor(readonly flag: T) {}
    is<O extends DD>(t: O): this is Flagged<O> {
        return t === this.flag; // compiler error
    }
}
```

The compiler informs me that:

> This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'O' and 'T'
> have no overlap.(2367)

Can anybody explain this? To me it seems obvious that both, `O` and `T`, are subsets of `DD` and could therefore have some overlap or not --- exactly what I want to test with the `is`.

Comment: you missed the public / private part in the constructor flag parameter

Comment: Late code "simplification" :-/ Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: this happens a lot in typescript, when the compiler fails to find any property in common between the two types it shows this errors, just cast one of them to DD

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this

```js
is<O extends DD>(t: O): this is Flagged<O> {
    const c: DD = t
    return c === this.flag; // no compiler error
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am more interested in an explanation what is going on there.

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed in a [Typescript issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31555) in a slightly different setting, namely code like

```ts
type Size = 'big' | 'small';
function isSame<O extends Size, T extends Size>(s1: O, s2: T): boolean {
  return s1 === s2;
}
```

To summarize the arguments:

> Why use two different generic type arguments, `O` and `T`, when they are supposed to be the same.

My take: half true, but as the example shows, the types can just overlap and that is exactly what we want to test. Further, the OPs original code shows an example where it cannot work without two generic type arguments.

> The error message is not ideal.

My take: indeed :-)

> There are ways to tell the compiler that two generic type arguments are related with the `extends` clause.

Well, yes, but `extends` specifies a subset, not a *potential* overlap. Yet for the OP, this could be an acceptable solution:

```ts
type DD = 'a' | 'b';
class Flagged<T extends DD> {
    constructor(readonly flag: T) {}
    is<O extends DD | T>(t: O): this is Flagged<O> {
        return t === this.flag;
    }
}
```

*Note the seemingly superfluous `| T` in the type argument of `is`.*